# TSQL Count of last rolling 10 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table as simple as two columns Name, Date   -- It is a table that has "Leads" in it when user inquiries from our website.

I need to produce a data set of lead count of last 10 rolling weeks?

The expected output is suppose to be

```
Starting Week -- Count
==============
10     SUM(Last 10 weeks)
9    SUM(Starting from Week 9 for Last 10 weeks)
8    SUM(Starting from Week 8 for Last 10 weeks)
```

and so on.. it will have 10 rows

its like sliding a week back and sum the last 10 weeks from there

any help?

Comment: The week is defined as Monday to Sunday

Answer (score 2):

You can do a Cumulative Sum on the Count like this:

```
select DATEPART(week, [Date]) AS weekNo
  ,sum(count(*)) 
   over (order by DATEPART(week, [Date])
         rows unbounded preceding)
from tab
where ...
group by DATEPART(week, [Date])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is *exactly* what the windowing clause is supposed to do.  However, you first need to aggregate the data:

```
select date, count(*) as cnt
from simple s
group by date;
```

Assuming that you have data on every day, then you want 70 days worth of counts.  You get that by summing the counts for 70 days.  That would be:

```
select date, count(*) as cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over
           (order by date rows between 69 preceding and current row)
from simple s
group by date;
```

That works for days.  To get this by weeks, you need to do something to convert days to weeks and then change the windowing clause.  You don't define a week, but this might be close to what you want:

```
select dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, date), date) as weekstart,
       count(*) as cnt,
       sum(count(*)) over
           (order by dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, date), date) rows between 9 preceding and current row)
from simple s
group by dateadd(day, 1 - datepart(weekday, date), date)
order by weekstart;
```

Comment: This does not quite work, since you are grouping by an expression the order by date throws an error of 

Column 'simple.date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user18620 . . . When converting the query for weeks, you need to change the `order by` to handle weeks rather than days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT Name,
       weekSlide + 1 AS weekSlide,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN weekDiff BETWEEN 0 AND 9 THEN 1 END) AS [Count]
FROM (
  SELECT Name,
         DATEPART(week, [Date]) AS weekNo,
         (x.c - DATEPART(week, [Date])) + 
         (YEAR(GETDATE()) - DATEPART(year, [Date])) * 52 - 
         y.weekSlide AS weekDiff,      
         y.weekSlide
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATEPART(week, GETDATE())) x(c) -- current week number
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS y(weekSlide)) t
GROUP BY Name, weekSlide
```

`weekSlide` is a counter of the *week window*, i.e. it is `0` for the week window containing the last 10 weeks starting from current date's week, `1` for the week window starting from previous week, etc.

`weekDiff` is a computed column containing the *offset* of [Date] for each `weekSlide`. A negative offset implies a [Date] that lies past the week window.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77c83/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
DECLARE @week INT, @end_date DATE
DECLARE @results AS TABLE (starting_week INT, count INT)

SET @week = 0
WHILE @week < 10
BEGIN
    SELECT @end_date = DATEADD(dd, @week * (-7), GETDATE())
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT (10 - @week),
           COUNT(1) FROM Leads
               WHERE Date BETWEEN (DATEADD(dd, -70, @end_date)) AND @end_date
    @week = @week + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @results
```

Edit: although Brian's question (comment added to your initial question) is a good one - if it's anything other than "rolling back from today", then you'd need to add another line of logic to the definition of `@end_date`.